# Wait for ExecutorChannel to finish in junit

Tags: spring, junit, spring-integration

I am using spring integration and junit.

```
@Test
public void testOnePojo() throws Exception {
    ExecutorChannel orderSendChannel = 
    context.getBean("validationChannel", ExecutorChannel.class);
    ExecutorChannel orderReceiveChannel = context.getBean("auditChannel", ExecutorChannel.class);
    orderReceiveChannel.subscribe(t -> {
         System.out.println(t);//I want to see this output     
    }); 
    orderSendChannel.send(getMessageMessage());
}
```

I cannot see the output from the receiving channel. JUnit exits after subscribing. It there a proper way to wait inside `testOnePojo` until `auditChannel` receives a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a [CoundDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) in your test and wait for the MessageHandler to handle your message. Your example would look something like this:

```
@Test
public void testOnePojo() throws Exception {
    final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    ExecutorChannel orderSendChannel =
        context.getBean("validationChannel", ExecutorChannel.class);
    ExecutorChannel orderReceiveChannel = context.getBean("auditChannel", ExecutorChannel.class);
    orderReceiveChannel.subscribe(t -> {
        System.out.println(t);//I want to see this output
        countDownLatch.countDown();
    });
    orderSendChannel.send(getMessageMessage());

    countDownLatch.await();
}
```

Comment: The answer is correct: you cannot verify something what happens on the other thread from main junit one. You have to use some thread barrier to catch the data .